# Edit Menu not showing for UITextField when iCloud+ "Hide my Email" is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios16

When iCloud+ "Hide my Email" feature is turned ON in iPhone Settings, "Cut/Copy/Paste" Edit Menu is not shown for any `UITextField` with `keyboardType` as `.email` Observed this issue in iOS 16.3.1. Is there any way to fix this issue ?